# Server Side Checkout vs Agent Side Checkout

Tags: teamcity

I've been reading through the TeamCity 4.x documentation, and I am confused what the difference between a server side checkout and an agent side checkout is, as mentioned in this snippet from their help section:

> Exclude checkout rules will only speed up **server-side** checkouts. **Agent-side** checkouts emulate the exclude checkout rules by checking out all the root directories mentioned as include rules and deleting the excluded directories. So, exclude checkout rules should generally be avoided for the agent-side checkout.

What is the difference between a server-side checkout and an agent-side checkout?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, here is the [answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5251095) from Pavel Sher (a JB guy) :

> The main reason why server side
>   checkout exists - is to simplify
>   administration overhead.
>
> With server side checkout you need to
>   install VCS client software on the
>   server only (applicable to Perforce,
>   Mercurial, TFS, Clearcase, VSS).
>   Network access to VCS repository can
>   also be opened to the server only. So
>   if you want to control who has access
>   to your sources repositories it is
>   probably better to use server side
>   checkout.
>
> As a side effect in some cases server
>   side checkout can lower load produced
>   on VCS repositories especially if
>   clean checkout is performed often.
>   This is because clean patches are
>   cached by server. However this is
>   environment specific, probably in some
>   cases agent side checkout will work
>   better.
>
> Exclude rules also are better
>   processed with server side checkout
>   because usually agent side checkout is
>   just an update and with most VCSes
>   there is no way to exclude some
>   directories during update operation.
>
> From the other hand because agent side
>   checkout is just an update or checkout
>   it creates necessary administration
>   directories (like .svn, CVS), so it
>   allows you to communicate with
>   repository from the build: commit
>   changes and so on. With server side
>   checkout such directories won't be
>   created.

Comment: So, with Server Side Check out, will the server push everything (or everything it somehow determines has changed since last build) to the build agent prior to a build?

Comment: or... exactly how it works ... NOT ;-) I have this teamcity build with server side checkout and a few rules; but weirdly, certain changes in the svn are never seen by the build! Then I updated to a newer version of Teamcity locally on my machines and it seemed to work. But alas! I can't get actual teamcity agents to be updated in my company.

Comment: Does anyone know what the TeamCity variable for the Git checkout directory is when "Automatically on server" is chosen? It is not the same as the working directory, since that is on the agent.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the official [TeamCity documentaion page](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD9/VCS+Checkout+Mode), which describes the difference. It was noticeably improved since the original question was asked.

Comment: Or here, for Team City version 8 http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Mode

Comment: I can't find any documentation on how to switch over to this mode. I really need it to fix my problem with symlinks. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found it, it's under advanced options on the VCS settings page.